# Vue.js Autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, axios

I am building a live search component with Vuejs. The search is working as expected. On keyup the method populates an unordered list. I am at a loss but need to:

1. Click on a selection from the search results and populate the input with that name.
2. Get the selected id.

Any suggestions?

The View

```
<label>Vendor:</label>
   <input type="text" v-model="vendor" v-on:keyup="get_vendors">
       <div class="panel-footer" v-if="vendors.length">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item for="vendor in vendors">
                    {{ vendor.vendor_name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
       </div>
```

The Script

```
export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                vendor:'',
                vendors: []
             }
        },
        methods: {
            get_vendors(){
                this.vendors = [];
                if(this.vendor.length > 0){
                    axios.get('search_vendors',{params: {vendor: this.vendor}}).then(response => 
                    {
                        this.vendors = response.data;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The Route

```
Route::get('search_vendors', 'vendorController@search_vendors');
```

The Controller

```
    public function search_vendors(Request $request){
        $vendors = vendor::where('vendor_name','LIKE','%'.$request->vendor.'%')->get();
        return response()->json($vendors);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Works nicely.

The View

```
<label>Vendor:</label>
<input type="text" v-model="vendor" v-on:keyup="get_vendors" class="col-xl-6 form-control ">
   <div class="panel-footer autocomplete-box col-xl-6">
      <ul class="list-group">
         <li v-for="(vendor,id) in vendors" @click="select_vendor(vendor)" class="list-group-item autocomplete-box-li">
            {{ vendor.vendor_name }}
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

The Script

```
 export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                vendor:'',
                vendor_id:'',
                vendors: []
             }
        },
        methods: {
            select_vendor(vendor){
                this.vendor = vendor.vendor_name
                this.vendor_id = vendor.id
                this.vendors = [];
            },
            get_vendors(){
                if(this.vendor.length == 0){
                    this.vendors = [];
                }
                if(this.vendor.length > 0){
                    axios.get('search_vendors',{params: {vendor: this.vendor}}).then(response => {
                        this.vendors = response.data;
                    });
                }
            },

        },
    }
</script>
```

The Route

```
Route::get('search_vendors', 'vendorController@search_vendors');
```

The Controller

```
  public function search_vendors(Request $request){
        $vendors = vendor::where('vendor_name','LIKE','%'.$request->vendor.'%')->get();
        return response()->json($vendors);
    }
```

The CSS

```
.autocomplete-box-li:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.autocomplete-box{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the id of the vendor you can do it using vendor.vendor_id which should be present in the vendor object which is returned from the server and if you want to populate the vendors array with new options you can have a [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) or a [@change](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-trigger-an-onchange-event/11081/4) ([binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html))  function to add the entered text field as the new vendor in the vendor array. Also, I would suggest that you download the [vue extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) as it will help you a lot in debugging

```
<label>Vendor:</label>
   <input type="text" v-model="vendor" v-on:keyup="get_vendors">
       <div class="panel-footer" v-if="vendors.length">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item for="(vendor,index) in vendors">
                    {{ index }}
                    {{ vendor.vendor_id }}
                    {{ vendor.vendor_name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
       </div>
```